# Two faces of same service..how to design it?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, design-patterns, service

I am implementing a service which has two faces? The service provides various methods to be used by User applications. the service may be a public/private service. it may be a OS service or a web service or in-memory.  I want one face for General type of user applications and another face for Special type of user applications. General user applications will not be able to see the methods provided for Special ones. There are some common methods used by both.

For example, if there a database and i design a service with CRUD methods on it. But i want two different faces of the service where in one face 'D' is hidden.

The way i achieved this is i created two separate interfaces with different methods names for the common ones and one of the interfaces does not have some methods. so 'two face'....

But is this the correct way to do it, is it real and acceptable in design?, or there is another way of doing it.

Comment: Why not go with privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is a proxy pattern and yes, it is an acceptable way to handle this kind of scenario.  Think of `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)`.  This method creates a proxy for the `List` and throws `UnsupportedOpperationException`s for the updating methods such as `boolean add(T)`, etc.  Now, the question is do you want to expose these methods but throw unchecked exceptions when called and keep the contract the same or do you remove the methods all together?  I tend to favor the latter or you will end up with a slew of incompatible interfaces as you have more and more permutations of what method calls are allowable but it really depends on your needs.  A proxy, by definition, has the same interface as the object it is controlling access to.

Now if you want to *build up* unsupported operations, just nest your proxies:

```
DAO crateReadOnlyProxy(DAO dao) {
  return new NoInsertProxy(new NoDeleteProxy(new NoUpdateProxy(dao)));
}
```

You only have 1 interface (`DAO`) with 4 implementations (in this example), the true implementation and then the 3 proxy implementations that just delegate their method calls to the underlying DAO (or DAO proxy).  Of course, to make life easier, you can create a `DAOProxyAdapter` class so you don't have to re-write all those delegate methods:

```
public class DAOProxyAdapter implements DAO {
  private DAO target;
  public DAOProxyAdapter(DAO target) { this.target = target; }
  public void insert(Object o) {target.insert(o); }
  public void delete(Object o) {target.delete(o); }
  public void update(Object o) {target.update(o); }
  public Object find(Object key) { return target.find(key); }
}
public class NoDeleteProxy extends DAOProxyAdapter {
  public NoDeleteProxy(DAO target) {super(target);}
  public void delete(Object o) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}
```